# Correct formatter should be for sending Timestamp data in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Good afternoon.

Trying to send Timestamp format data through a Spring Booth controller.

Before that I used LocalDateTime, but now I needed to change it to Timestamp.

When I try to send data, I get an error:

> projectTheoreticalLeadTimeError -> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp' for property 'projectTheoreticalLeadTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.sql.Timestamp] for value '2020-05-01T12:12'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

The formatter used for LocalDateTime worked great with the configuration:

```
@Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
        registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
    }
```

***The formatter that I tried to do for Timestamp does not work with the configuration:***

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
    registrar.setDateFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
}
```

Tell me which correct formatter should be for sending Timestamp data?

Comment: please format you stack trace

Comment: And I think it is clearly said in the error `Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]`

Comment: Yes, I tried with this format, the result is the same

Comment: please format you stack trace

Comment: for just checking, try to give a string formatted in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]` rather than `'2020-05-01T12:12'`? just check this works or not

Comment: Yes, it works, but I can only send data in this format 2020-05-01T12: 12 using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local , apparently here we need to somehow transform using Javascript ((

Comment: yea, i think that's the way.